# Trying to figure out a way to output PHP as plain text

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out the php output of a shortcode in WordPress. I need to know the actual php this short code generates so I can hard code it into the template.

I've found the function responsible for that shortcode but I need to know if it is possible to  echo the php as plain text so I can copy it

```
add_shortcode("thumbnailgrid", "thumbnailgrid_handler");

add_filter('query_vars', 'tbpage_vars');


function tbpage_vars($qvars)
{
    $qvars[] = 'tg_page';
    return $qvars;
}


//This is what takes the shortcode and generates the php
function thumbnailgrid_handler($atts) {

    wp_enqueue_style('thumbnailgrid', plugins_url('css/thumbnailgrid.css', __FILE__));
    $tg = new thumbnailgrid();
    $output = $tg->thumbnailgrid_function($atts);

    return $output;
}

class thumbnailgrid
{
    function thumbnailgrid_function($atts) {
        wp_reset_query();
        if ($atts)
        {
            extract( shortcode_atts( array(
                'height' => '',                
                'width' => ''
            ), $atts ) );
           unset($atts["height"]);
           unset($atts["width"]);

           $the_query = new WP_Query($atts);
        }


        else
        {
            $the_query = new WP_Query('posts_per_page  = -1');
        }


    $ret = '<div class="thumbnailblock"><div class="thumbnailgridcontainer">';
    $style = "";
    if ($height || $width)
    {
        $style = ' style="';
        if ($height)
            $style .= 'height:' .$height . ';';

        if ($width)
            $style .= 'width:' .$width . ';';
        $style .= '"';
     } 
      while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :$the_query->the_post();
        $titlelength = 20;
        $permalink = get_permalink();
        $title = get_the_title();
        //$thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail();
        $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image_id,'thumbnail', true);
        if ($image_id)
            $thumbnail = '<img src="' .$image_url[0] .'"' .$style . '/>';
        else
            $thumbnail = '';
        $tt = $title; 
        $im = '<div class="postimage"' .$style .'>
            <a href="'. $permalink .'" title="'.$title.'">'. $thumbnail .'</a> 
            </div><!-- .postimage -->';

            $ret .=
            '<div class="griditemleft"' .$style .'>'
            . $im ;

            $ret .= '<div class="postimage-title">
                <a href="'. $permalink .'" title="'. $title .'">'.$tt .'</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .griditemleft -->';



    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    $ret .=  '</div></div>';
    return $ret;
}

function bkthumbnailgrid_function($atts) {
    if ($atts)
    {
       extract( shortcode_atts( array(
            'height' => '',                
            'width' => ''
        ), $atts ) );
       unset($atts["height"]);
       unset($atts["width"]);

       $the_query = new WP_Query($atts);
    }
    $style = "";
    if ($height || $width)
    {
        $style = ' style="';
        if ($height)
            $style .= 'height:' .$height . ';';

        if ($width)
            $style .= 'width:' .$width . ';';
        $style .= '"';
     } 
    $titlelength = 20; // Length of the post titles shown below the thumbnails

    $bookmarks = get_bookmarks( $atts );

    $ret = '';
     $titlelength = 20;
    foreach ( $bookmarks as $bookmark ) { 



        $permalink = $bookmark->link_url;
        $title = $bookmark->link_name;
        $target = $bookmark->link_target;
        $thumbnail = $bookmark->link_image;
        if ($target != '')
        {
            $target = ' target="' .$target .'"';


        }

       if (strlen($title) > $titlelength)
            $tt = mb_substr($title, 0, $titlelength) . ' ...';
        else 
             $tt = $title; 
            $im = '<div class="postimage"' .$style .'>
                <a href="'. $permalink .'" title="'.$title.'"'. $target .'><img src="'. $thumbnail .'"' . $style .'/></a> 
            </div><!-- .postimage -->';
            $ret .=
            '<div class="griditemleft"' .$style .'>'
            . $im .
            '<div class="postimage-title">
                <a href="'. $permalink .'" title="'. $title .'">'.$tt .'</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .griditemleft -->';


    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
    return $ret;
}
}
```

Again, I need a way to echo or print output the raw php as plain text that comes out so that I can copy it

Comment: That's alot of code & most developers here would not wish to add extra clicks to their path of assistance. I'd recommend minimzing the code to the most problematic zone & post in your question body

Comment: Are you trying to just print out the code, or do you want it to print out with variables set to their values?

Comment: Just the code is all that's needed

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

header('Content-type: text/plain');

print file_get_contents("somepage.php");

?>
```